# How to check which place in panel was clicked? GWT

Tags: gwt, onclick, panel

How can I check which place in Panel Was clicked? I know, I have this some functions:

getClientX, getClientY, getNativeButton, getRelativeX, getRelativeY, getScreenX, getScreenY, getX, getY

but how can I check which click Was near right side of panel and which was near left side of the panel?

I can't add to the Panel two div's with 50% width and detect in that way..

More info: 
It's a lot of panels. I must do this in each of panel. I don't know how many panels we have. We have got a constans width of each panel = 400px.

Regards!

Comment: what do you want to know, the coordinates of the click event, or the specific DOM element inside the panel which was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're handling an `onClick` event or similar for a panel, you can get the cursor position with `getClientX` or something similar. Then just get the position and size of the panel and simply check what you're closet to; all elements are rectangular, so shouldn't be too difficult to just write four `if`s for it.

The `getElement()` method will give you the panel's underlying element, so you may need to use that to get the exact size and position.